# Minimum number of samples to train XGBoost without overfitting

Tags: neural-network, classification, xgboost, overfitting

When using Neural Networks for image processing I learned a rule of thumb: to avoid overfitting, supply at least 10 training examples for every neuron.

Is there a similar rule of thumb for classifiers such as `XGBoost`, presumably taking into account the number of features and estimators?

And, considering the 'curse of dimensionality' shouldn't the rule of thumb be that `n_training` is geometric in `n_dimensions`, and not linear?

Answer (score 1):

It's completely true that the number of examples should be related to features. But it is not only the number of features because the range of a number(max-min and count of different number) is also important. On the other hand, if you have noise you need more examples, so it's related to your dataset.

Comment: look like you want to do "ensemble". search it if I am right

Comment: Is it doable with only 36 data points and 2 features?

Comment: it's related to how much your problem is complex. Furthermore, for this amount of data, I'm not sure if XGBoost is a good choice

Comment: The range of features is irrelevant for tree-based models, but you're right that the count of distinct values (and their distribution) is relevant.

Answer (score 1):

This is not only a number of sample, this is also a question of depth.

The higher depth you have, the more you're likely to overfit.

You can reduce the overfit by adding a high number of trees, that allows you to "steady" your algorithm

Comment: Or by other parameters that reduce overfitting of XGBoost, for example minimum weight to create split (`min_child_weight` in XGBoost package in Python).